# Php (SF2) page not updating with new code

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, nginx, php

Running **nginx** with **php5-fpm** and **mysql** at **ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS**.
Whenever i update my code (**SF2/PHP**) the changes remain unchanged whenever i load my page.

How can i figure out what is happening?

- It might be /var/www directory issues. Although opening file with nano shows me the file is really being updated.
- It might be nginx / php5-fpm having some issues. (tried reloading/restarting, no effect)
- It might be the following code

Example of what's happening:

*At my page /users:*

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for JMS\Serializer\Serializer::serialize(), called in /var/www/webshop/src/AppBundle/Controller/UsersController.php on line 35 and defined
```

*With the following code:*

```
public function getUsersAction() {
    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $doctrineUsers = $doctrine->getRepository("AppBundle:User")->findAll();

    $users = array();

    foreach($doctrineUsers as $user) {
        $users[$user->getUsername()] = array(
            "id" => $user->getId()
        );
    }

    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    return $serializer->serialize($users);
}
```

Than i changed that piece of code having

```
return $serializer->serialize($users, 'json');
```

But the error remains the same, telling me i miss an argument.
I can now even completely change the code around, e.g

```
return 'WHATEVER';
```

And it still displays the same error page.

Comment: What happens when you clear the cache manually? rm -rf app/cache/*

Comment: cache:clear rarely does a proper job for me. I tend to delete the folder manually in my ide

Comment: I will see what happens, when the coffee is done! :-)

Comment: This, sadly, did not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `php-opcache` enabled which caches the whole class.

Try restarting `nginx` and fireing up the page again. I have encountered this with `APC` enabled on `httpd` so it should be similar...

Also, make sure that you run `app_dev.php` and that cache is not enabled within the file. Bundled Symfony2 `app_dev.php` has a commented lines.